# Scrapy for million pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** a video website with approximatively 10 million pages using scrapy. My script stops (bugs) after approximatively 430 000 pages scraped. What would you recommand to help me **scrape** all the urls of the website (like dockerisations, etc.) ?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Depends on the reason _why_ it stops. Any details?

Answer (score -1):

My intuitive guess is that you have a memory leak! Your computer filled up all its RAM and didn't know to continue.

It may be worth reading up on how garbage collection works and then thinking deeply about what things in your codebase are being kept referenced in memory. Are you for instance keeping a global dictionary of every page you have visited? Or any other infinite sized cache?

- https://stackify.com/python-garbage-collection/

Another workaround approach is to persist your scraped webpages to disk, as well as filesystem/database lists of downloaded/unvisited urls. This would allow your program to terminate at any time and restart where it left off (read the list of unvisited urls from disk again). Also think about the multiprocessing edgecase if you have two or more instances of your script running at the same time.

You could then in theory run your script in a bash for/while loop, let it memory leak (ugly), but have it keep restarting until it finally runs out of urls.